# Crash on back click from pdf file to fragment

Tags: android

I'm using fragment and from that fragment i'm opening a pdf file when i click on back button to go fragment from pdf file it gives me that exception

---

```
10-11 13:22:23.429: E/AndroidRuntime(20035): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
 Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.ClassCastException: 
com.software.notes.learn.HomeActivity@4117ef58 must implement OnURLSelectedListener
```

Comment: Post your code of `HomeActivity`.

Comment: Does `HomeActivity` implement `OnURLSelectedListener`?

Comment: no it's just an activity. on back click it should come to FileView fragment from pdf file not HomeActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, you are passing an instance as an `OnURLSelectedListener`. At some point you are passing your HomeActivity instance as the `OnURLSelectedListener`. However, `HomeActivity` does not implement `OnURLSelectedListener`.

Make sure you are passing the right instance (watch out with using `this` with nested methods) which implements `OnURLSelectedListener` or make sure `HomeActivity` implements `OnURLSelectedListener`.